# No traffic over ASA 5505 site to site tunnel

Tags: cisco-asa

I'm not seeing traffic in either direction on a new site-to-site VPN. (Two others are fine) I can't see what is wrong.

```
:
ASA Version 9.2(4)13 
!
hostname wss
domain-name xxxxxxxxxxxx.com
enable password qJtG/3webvseVHy/m encrypted
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 209.xxx.xxx.250 255.255.255.248 
!
ftp mode passive
clock timezone EST -5
clock summer-time EDT recurring
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 domain-name xxxxxxxxxxxx.com
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
object network 209.xxx.xxx.249
 host 209.xxx.xxx.249
object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.100.100.0_24
 subnet 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0
object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.0.0_24
 subnet 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
access-list outside_cryptomap extended permit ip 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.0.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.0.0_24 destination static NETWORK_OBJ_10.100.100.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_10.100.100.0_24 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
!
object network obj_any
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
!
nat (inside,outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 209.xxx.xxx.249 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
http server enable
http 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set myset esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_cryptomap
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer 71.xxx.xxx.34 
crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5
crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES 3DES AES AES192 AES256
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-192
 integrity sha
 group 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 20
 encryption aes
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 30
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 40
 encryption des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable outside
crypto ikev1 enable outside
crypto ikev1 am-disable
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
no ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh timeout 5
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0

dhcpd address 192.168.0.20-192.168.0.70 inside
dhcpd dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 interface inside
dhcpd enable inside
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
group-policy GroupPolicy_71.xxx.xxx.34 internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_71.xxx.xxx.34 attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 
tunnel-group DefaultL2LGroup ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****
tunnel-group 71.xxx.xxx.34 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 71.xxx.xxx.34 general-attributes
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_71.xxx.xxx.34
tunnel-group 71.xxx.xxx.34 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 

  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:a50bb6e11ewrgertgba5362d09896cd2
: end
```

Here is the other side:

```
: 
: Serial Number: JMXXXXXX03M
: Hardware:   ASA5505, 512 MB RAM, CPU Geode 500 MHz
:
ASA Version 9.2(4)13 
!
hostname ortho
domain-name xxxxxxxxxx.com
enable password y4Cbeg45a6TNeJj encrypted
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any6
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any6
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any6 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any6 eq domain
passwd lWz.HrbgH8Pg2vLY encrypted
names
ip local pool mypool 192.168.19.10-192.168.19.20 mask 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.100.100.252 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 71.xxx.xxx.34 255.255.255.248 
!
boot system disk0:/asa924-13-k8.bin
boot system disk0:/asa924-k8.bin
ftp mode passive
clock timezone EST -5
clock summer-time EDT recurring
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 domain-name xxxxxxxx.com
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object network obj-10.100.100.0
 subnet 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0
object network obj-10.100.101.0
 subnet 10.100.101.0 255.255.255.0
object network obj-192.168.19.0
 subnet 192.168.19.0 255.255.255.0
object network obj-192.168.20.0
 subnet 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
object network obj-10.100.200.0
 subnet 10.100.200.0 255.255.255.0
object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.32_27
 subnet 192.168.1.32 255.255.255.224
object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.19.0_27
 subnet 192.168.19.0 255.255.255.224
object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.100.100.0_24
 subnet 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0
object network 192.168.19.0
 subnet 192.168.19.0 255.255.255.0
object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.0.0_24
 subnet 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
object-group service allowedports tcp
 port-object eq https
 port-object eq smtp
 port-object eq www
access-list tovergennes extended permit ip 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.101.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.101.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 object 192.168.19.0 
access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list split standard permit 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list split standard permit 10.100.200.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list split standard permit 10.100.101.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list allowin extended permit gre any4 any4 
access-list allowin extended permit ip object obj-10.100.100.0 object obj-192.168.19.0 
access-list outside_cryptomap_30 extended permit ip 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.200.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_access_out extended deny tcp 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 any eq smtp 
access-list outside_cryptomap_2 extended permit ip 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 
no pager
logging enable
logging buffered debugging
logging asdm notifications
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm image disk0:/asdm-761.bin
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (inside,any) source static obj-10.100.100.0 obj-10.100.100.0 destination static obj-10.100.101.0 obj-10.100.101.0 no-proxy-arp
nat (inside,any) source static obj-10.100.100.0 obj-10.100.100.0 destination static 192.168.19.0 192.168.19.0 no-proxy-arp
nat (inside,any) source static obj-10.100.100.0 obj-10.100.100.0 destination static obj-192.168.19.0 obj-192.168.19.0 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (inside,any) source static obj-10.100.100.0 obj-10.100.100.0 destination static obj-192.168.20.0 obj-192.168.20.0 no-proxy-arp
nat (inside,any) source static obj-10.100.100.0 obj-10.100.100.0 destination static obj-10.100.200.0 obj-10.100.200.0 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (inside,outside) source static any any destination static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.32_27 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.32_27 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_10.100.100.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_10.100.100.0_24 destination static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.19.0_27 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.19.0_27 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
!
object network obj_any
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
access-group inside_access_out out interface inside
access-group allowin in interface outside
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 71.xxx.xxx.33 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication enable console LOCAL 
aaa authentication http console LOCAL 
aaa authentication serial console LOCAL 
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
aaa authentication telnet console LOCAL 
http server enable 5555
http 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set myset esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal myset
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-128-SHA
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-128-MD5
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-192-SHA
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-192-MD5
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-256-SHA
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-256-MD5
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-3DES-SHA
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-3DES-MD5
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-DES-SHA
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-DES-MD5
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-

SHA ESP-DES-MD5
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256 AES192 AES 3DES DES
crypto map mymap 1 match address outside_cryptomap_2
crypto map mymap 1 set peer 209.xxx.xxx.250 
crypto map mymap 1 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5
crypto map mymap 1 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES 3DES AES AES192 AES256 myset ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA
crypto map mymap 20 match address toes
crypto map mymap 20 set peer 64.xxx.xxx.145 
crypto map mymap 20 set ikev1 transform-set myset
crypto map mymap 20 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal myset
crypto map mymap 30 match address outside_cryptomap_30
crypto map mymap 30 set peer 69.xxx.xxx.14 
crypto map mymap 30 set ikev1 transform-set myset
crypto map mymap 30 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal myset
crypto map mymap 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map mymap interface outside
crypto ca trustpoint VPN
 enrollment terminal
 subject-name CN=ortho
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_Launcher_Access_TrustPoint_0
 enrollment self
 subject-name CN=10.100.100.252,CN=ortho
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ca certificate chain ASDM_Launcher_Access_TrustPoint_0
 certificate 8b2a9757
    3082022f 30820198 a0030201 0202048b 2a975730 0d06092a 864886f7 0d010105 
    0500305c 31133011 06035504 03130a6d 6964646c 65627572 79311730 15060355 
    0403130e 31302e31 30302e31 30302e32 3532312c 302a0609 2a864886 f70d0109 
    02161d6d 6964646c 65627572 792e6275 726c696e 67746f6e 64727567 2e636f6d 
    301e170d 31363037 32393135 31373434 5a170d32 36303732 37313531 3734345a 
    305c3113 30110603 55040313 0a6d6964 646c6562 75727931 17301506 03550403 
    130e3130 2e313030 2e313030 2e323532 312c302a 06092a86 4886f70d 01090216 
    1d6d6964 646c6562 7572792e 6275726c 696e6774 6f6e6472 75672e63 6f6d3081 
    9f300d06 092a8648 86f70d01 03442eee 03818d00 30818902 818100d1 018faa97 
    bf6b8ae0 8ce5d37b 5c6f433c c6d70271 f1c1115e 4daa2b7f d1cd2ea7 158aa154 
    239b4229 d8147393 ec8637e6 d7ff2ccf 6a719c67 764b71ba 0750eb2e b40e18e0 
    a45899ce 2dcf23b8 91d9684c 2c617a01 3cb98e1c 772daec7 2c996780 f1fa7fe5 
    b01c22dc a27cbb08 e1353d10 fdf97ba1 1e6a23ed bf92f11e ac956b02 03010001 
    300d0609 2a864886 f70d0101 05050003 818100ab 76aeb2f2 ccc9d166 3cb2f21a 
    488b9639 69142eb9 6a2ff4c9 c95abde6 f0ebc4f2 e0e559f1 71fb927e cc208449 
    86f7a8da fa90fd87 a6b1c2af 032ba70e b3df42bf d2edd591 2f1ee61b c7815f55 
    d5cd9bab 0b4fce88 a91905dc da035584 e538febd f5413f3b 3508a721 77cb021a 
    881126e1 9f93508e 3c923447 7f54b12c 1b6a6d
  quit
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 20
 encryption aes
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 30
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 40
 encryption des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable outside client-services port 443
crypto ikev2 remote-access trustpoint ASDM_Launcher_Access_TrustPoint_0
crypto ikev1 enable outside
crypto ikev1 am-disable
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.255 inside
telnet timeout 5
ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 inside
ssh timeout 60
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
management-access inside
vpn-sessiondb max-other-vpn-limit 10
vpn-sessiondb max-anyconnect-premium-or-essentials-limit 2

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection scanning-threat shun except ip-address 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0
threat-detection scanning-threat shun except ip-address 10.100.101.0 255.255.255.0
threat-detection scanning-threat shun except ip-address 10.100.200.0 255.255.255.0
threat-detection scanning-threat shun duration 3600
threat-detection statistics
threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept rate-interval 30 burst-rate 400 average-rate 200
ssl trust-point ASDM_Launcher_Access_TrustPoint_0 outside
ssl trust-point ASDM_Launcher_Access_TrustPoint_0 inside
ssl trust-point ASDM_Launcher_Access_TrustPoint_0 inside vpnlb-ip
webvpn
 no anyconnect-essentials
 anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-win-3.1.14018-k9.pkg 1
 anyconnect profiles RemoteAccessIKEv2_client_profile disk0:/RemoteAccessIKEv2_client_profile.xml
 anyconnect enable
 tunnel-group-list enable
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 vpn-idle-timeout 120
 webvpn
  anyconnect ssl keepalive none
  anyconnect dpd-interval client none
  anyconnect dpd-interval gateway none
  anyconnect ssl compression deflate
  customization value DfltCustomization
group-policy GroupPolicy_RemoteUsers internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_RemoteUsers attributes
 wins-server none
 dns-server none
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev2 
 default-domain value burlingtondrug.com
group-policy GroupPolicy_RemoteAccessIKEv2 internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_RemoteAccessIKEv2 attributes
 wins-server none
 dns-server value 10.100.100.4
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev2 ssl-clientless
 default-domain value phsrx.local
 webvpn
  anyconnect profiles value RemoteAccessIKEv2_client_profile type user
group-policy GroupPolicy2 internal
group-policy GroupPolicy2 attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 
group-policy GroupPolicy1 internal
group-policy GroupPolicy1 attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 
group-policy GroupPolicy_209.xxx.xxx.250 internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_209.xxx.xxx.250 attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 
group-policy marble internal
group-policy marble attributes
 wins-server value 10.100.100.4
 dns-server value 10.100.100.4
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 l2tp-ipsec 
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value split
username llauf password drnUg2FB/kwVbg5S encrypted
username llauf attributes
 service-type nas-prompt
username gregs password SgGYd9kk/N7wNpyb encrypted
username gregs attributes
 service-type nas-prompt
username phsrx password LFjGdPBp3.PJH2wz encrypted privilege 15
username kathyd password 0y8FY/jATMgQeSNR encrypted
username kathyd attributes
 service-type nas-prompt
username dianeg password ZEpP2RmvIWwlezst encrypted
username dianeg attributes
 service-type nas-prompt
username anetap password mjdjyXum3raO74y3 encrypted
username anetap attributes
 service-type nas-prompt
username mboise password DHv.i0NLnFnAH2sR encrypted
username mboise attributes
 service-type nas-prompt
tunnel-group 64.xxx.xxx.145 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 64.xxx.xxx.145 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****
tunnel-group marble type remote-access
tunnel-group marble general-attributes
 address-pool mypool
 default-group-policy marble
tunnel-group marble ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
tunnel-group 69.xxx.xxx.14 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 69.xxx.xxx.14 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****
tunnel-group 209.xxx.xxx.250 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 209.xxx.xxx.250 general-attributes
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_209.xxx.xxx.250
tunnel-group 209.xxx.xxx.250 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****
tunnel-group RemoteAccessIKEv2 type remote-access
tunnel-group RemoteAccessIKEv2 general-attributes
 address-pool mypool
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_RemoteAccessIKEv2
tunnel-group RemoteAccessIKEv2 webvpn-attributes
 group-alias RemoteAccessIKEv2 enable
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
 class class-default
  user-statistics accounting
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
call-home
 profile CiscoTAC-1
  no active
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
  destination address email callhome@cisco.com
  destination transport-method http
  subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic
  subscribe-to-alert-group environment
  subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily
hpm topN enable
Cryptochecksum:74fc0f94854gete59566de608cafc
```

Comment: From a "show nat" command, is the twin nat statement of: nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.0.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.0.0_24 destination static NETWORK_OBJ_10.100.100.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_10.100.100.0_24 no-proxy-arp route-lookup ... at the top of your NAT list?

Comment: Please post the config of the other side as well. What do you mean with sporadically? When you ping from one end to the other does the tunnel always come up, or only some of the time? Also, when the tunnel is up and you ping across do you see any counters increase in `show crypto ipsec sa` output on either end?

Comment: "Sporadically" wasn't the best choice of words. The tunnel shows up in the ASDM monitor but I am unable to ping the other side. I will post the config of the other side when I can get there in a few hours.

Comment: I've just added the config from the other side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found i was missing a NAT exemption on one side. Added it and it is working now.